# strange CopyResource result with ATI Radeon card

Tags: c++, directx-11

I get strange results, when I try to copy the rendered texture into a background texture for later use, using the CopyResource command. this is whats comming out:

[image]

I don't get any dx11 warnings or errors.
this also only happens while using an ATI Radeon card.
I also tried on 5 other nvidia cards and the output looks fine.
I downloaded the newest drivers and also I tried older ones, but nothing changed.

I can not post the code, anyway it is to huge. I only want to know, if some one also had something like this, and if so, how did you solved it? 
Is there a better way to copy textures using another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that the problem is easy solveable. After a long debugging session
I saw, that the source texture was also bound to the render output. This gives no warnings or errors and is valid on nvidia cards, but my radeon card (AMD Radeon R7 M370) does not like it.
So I changed my code to:

```
OMSetRenderTargets(1, nullptr, nullptr);
CopyResource(...
```

and the bug was fixed. maybe someone helps this answer to solve the same problem.